# Mui DatePicker v6: How to change default icon and its position through slots

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, mui-x

I need this:
[image]

instead of this:
[image]

But now the date picker(@mui/x-date-pickers 6.x) has switched to slots, and there are very few examples on the Web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-datepicker-change-icon-and-its-position-ylzn4n?file=/demo.tsx

Code for adding startAdornment for your field:

```
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker'
import BugReportIcon from "@mui/icons-material/BugReport";

//...

<DatePicker
  label="mui datapicker"
  slotProps={{
    textField: {
      InputProps: { startAdornment: <BugReportIcon /> }
    }
  }}
/>
```

Code for changing the default date picker icon:

```
   <DatePicker
     slots={{
       inputAdornment: BugReportIcon
     }}
   />
```

Code for change icon and its position:

```
<DatePicker
  slots={{
    inputAdornment: BugReportIcon
  }}
  slotProps={{
    inputAdornment: {
      position: 'start'
    }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: This is great and just what I needed! is it possible to change the icon color? I have the following in my theme, but when I use the solution above, the color is not applied:  
MuiIconButton: { defaultProps: { color: 'info', size: 'small' } }

Comment: @sweetpea Hi, try to add className to the icon componentm like: <CalendarToday className={classNamesInputIcon} />

Comment: @sweetpea look at the 55th line of code - https://gist.github.com/harddownloader/6c8e73a96be94e9f61c08f8cad82f4c1

Comment: @sweetpea change the icon color with `<DatePicker slotProps={{ openPickerButton: { color: 'error' } }} />`

Answer (score 1):

the following worked for me:

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

const getInputAdornment = () => {
    return (
        <InputAdornment position="start">
            <IconButton onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
                <BugReportIcon />
            </IconButton>
        </InputAdornment>
    );
};

<DatePicker
    onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
    open={open}
    slots={{ inputAdornment: getInputAdornment }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the excellent answer by [Serafim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76503093/6896486), this is how to set default values for `DatePicker` icon in the `Theme` object if you are using `<ThemeProvider>` in your application:

1. Modify the MUI `Components` interface to include `MuiDatePicker`.

```
import '@mui/material/styles';
import type { DatePickerProps } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import type { ComponentsOverrides, ComponentsVariants, Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import type { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {

  interface ComponentNameToClassKey {
    MuiDatePicker: 'root' | 'value' | 'unit';
  }

  interface ComponentsPropsList {
    MuiDatePicker: Partial<DatePickerProps<Dayjs>>;
  }

  interface Components {
    MuiDatePicker?: {
      defaultProps?: DatePickerProps<Dayjs>;
      styleOverrides?: Partial<ComponentsOverrides<Theme>['MuiDatePicker']>,
      variants?: ComponentsVariants['MuiDatePicker'];
    }
  }
}
```

2. Add the MuiDatePicker to the `Theme` components, and change the `defaultProps` and `styleOverrides` to meet your needs.

```
export const myTheme: ThemeOptions = {
  components: {
    MuiDatePicker: {
      defaultProps: {
        slotProps: {
          inputAdornment: {
            position: 'start'
          },
          openPickerButton: {
            color: 'error',
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

Now `DatePicker` can be used in the application without all the boilerplate.

[See related MUI docs here](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/creating-themed-components/#typescript)